# Multiple Filters on MatTable

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I've been trying to apply multi column filtering i.e a text input in column headers  will filter only on the contents of the column.So far I've been able to make it work by overriding `filterPredicate` of `MatTableDataSource` but once I override the default filtering which is across columns no longer works.

```
export class TableFilteringExample implements OnInit
{
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);

  positionFilter = new FormControl();
  nameFilter = new FormControl();

  filteredValues =
  {
    position: '',
    name: '',
    weight: '',
    symbol: ''
  };

  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.positionFilter.valueChanges.subscribe((positionFilterValue) =>
    {
      this.filteredValues['position'] = positionFilterValue;
      this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filteredValues);
    });

    this.nameFilter.valueChanges.subscribe((nameFilterValue) =>
    {
      this.filteredValues['name'] = nameFilterValue;
      this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filteredValues);
    });

    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = this.customFilterPredicate();
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string)
  {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }

  customFilterPredicate()
  {
    const myFilterPredicate = function(data: PeriodicElement, filter: string): boolean
    {
      let searchString = JSON.parse(filter);

      return data.position.toString().trim().indexOf(searchString.position) !== -1 && data.name.toString().trim().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString.name)!== -1;
    }

    return myFilterPredicate;
  }
}
```

What I'm looking for is once column filter is applied the default filter should update the existing filter criteria and return the further filtered data.

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbakxo-rrctcf?file=app%2Ftable-filtering-example.ts)**

Comment: Can we optimize the above code like for all the filter i need to write this.filter.valueChanges code instead of that can we use something to reduce that much line of repeated code for mutiple filters

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you just forgot to call `toLowerCase()` for `searchString.name`

data.name.toString().trim().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString.name.toLowerCase())!== -1;

---

EDIT:
One approach is to create a global filter field in your Component class.

```
globalFilter = '';
```

---

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [ngModel]="globalFilter" (ngModelChange)="applyFilter($event)" placeholder="Filter">
</mat-form-field>
```

---

```
applyFilter(filter) {
    this.globalFilter = filter;
    this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filteredValues);
}
```

---

Then try to filter using global filter first before the other fields.

```
  customFilterPredicate() {
    const myFilterPredicate = (data: PeriodicElement, filter: string): boolean => {
      var globalMatch = !this.globalFilter;

      if (this.globalFilter) {
        // search all text fields
        globalMatch = data.name.toString().trim().toLowerCase().indexOf(this.globalFilter.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
      }

      if (!globalMatch) {
        return;
      }

      let searchString = JSON.parse(filter);
      return data.position.toString().trim().indexOf(searchString.position) !== -1 &&
        data.name.toString().trim().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString.name.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    }
    return myFilterPredicate;
  }
```

Here's the working app:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbakxo-5jeaic

Comment: Nope.That's not the issue.I can't seem to figure out a way to make all three filters work at the same time.
Only the filters in column headers work.Do I need to roll a custom dataSource? but that would take lot of time given my understanding of rxjs.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

In Angular Material Tables, you can add multi colum filter using **filterPredicate** property on mat-tables and providing them a **customFilter** method as shown below

**Source [Link](https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-material-table-custom-filter-using-select-box/)**

**Demo [Link](https://freakyjolly.com/demo/Angular/angular-material-table-custom-filters-for-multiple-specific-column/)**

[image]

```
        ngOnInit() {

        // Overrride default filter behaviour of Material Datatable
        this.dataSource.filterPredicate = this.createFilter();
        }

        ...
        ...

        // Custom filter method fot Angular Material Datatable
        createFilter() {
        let filterFunction = function (data: any, filter: string): boolean {
          let searchTerms = JSON.parse(filter);
          let isFilterSet = false;
          for (const col in searchTerms) {
            if (searchTerms[col].toString() !== '') {
              isFilterSet = true;
            } else {
              delete searchTerms[col];
            }
          }

          let nameSearch = () => {
            let found = false;
            if (isFilterSet) {
              for (const col in searchTerms) {
                searchTerms[col].trim().toLowerCase().split(' ').forEach(word => {
                  if (data[col].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(word) != -1 && isFilterSet) {
                    found = true
                  }
                });
              }
              return found
            } else {
              return true;
            }
          }
          return nameSearch()
        }
        return filterFunction
        }
```

Comment: What we need to change for multi select dropdown search