# Filter in Angular Material

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, typescript, express

I am new to this angular, and I made a table of students. My problem is I want to filter through by year and then after that, I need to filter it by username or by LRN (Learner Reference Number). All my code is working well if I filter it individually but when I try to filter by year then followed by the username, it does not work.

**all-students-component.ts**

```js
    filterFullName(value: string): void {
        this.dataSource.filter = value.trim().toLocaleLowerCase();
        this.dataSource.filterPredicate = function (data, filter: string): boolean {
          return data.fullName.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(filter)
        }
    }

    filterLrn(value: string): void {
        this.dataSource.filter = value.trim().toLocaleLowerCase();
        this.dataSource.filterPredicate = function (data, filter: string): boolean {
         return data.lrn.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(filter);
        }
    }

    filterYear(value: string): void {
       this.dataSource.filter = value.trim().toLocaleLowerCase();
       this.dataSource.filterPredicate = function (data, filter: string): boolean {
        return data.date.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(filter)
       }
    }
```

**all-students-component.html**

```html
    <div>
     <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Search by {{typeSearch}}</mat-label>
        <input type="number" matInput autocomplete="off" *ngIf='lrn === true' (click)='lrn = true'
            [(ngModel)]="searchLrn" (keyup)="filterLrn($event.target.value)">
        <input type="text" matInput autocomplete="off" *ngIf='lrn === false' [(ngModel)]="fullName"
            (keyup)="filterFullName($event.target.value)">
        <mat-hint align="end">Search using LRN or Name</mat-hint>
    </mat-form-field>

    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" class='menuIcon'>
        <mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
    </button>

    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
        <button mat-menu-item (click)=' typeSearch = "LRN"; lrn= true '>LRN</button>
        <button mat-menu-item (click)=' typeSearch = "Name (Last Name, First name)"; lrn= false '>Name</button>
    </mat-menu>

    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Search by Year</mat-label>
        <input type="text" matInput autocomplete="off" [(ngModel)]="date"
            (keyup)="filterYear($event.target.value)">
     </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Filters on MatTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52007176/multiple-filters-on-mattable)

Comment: I've linked the  existing question with working answer (and stackblitz example included). Basically, datasource can have only one filter value and predicate. So when you change it, you remove the old filtering. So you need kind of an "filter object" with multiple properties that you will serialize and pass as filter value (which can be only string). Then you deserialize it inside the filterPredicate and use that to filter base on two (or more) properties.